# Creating remote powershell session to my O365 exchange tenant in Azure functions

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-functions

I'm trying to write a powershell function on the new azure function service.
The basic stuff work but when I attempt to create a new remote session to my exchange O365 tenant, the function simply stops processing when getting to the New-PSSession line.
There is no problem to create a remote session in azure automate powershell.
Am I missing something here?

```
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
$username = "xxxx"
$password = convertto-securestring "yyyyy" -asplaintext -force
$Creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$Session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $Creds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession -Session $Session
```

Comment: It might be an issue with which PowerShell commands are available and allowed on App Service. I trired reproing but I'm not familiar with what info I'm supposed to be setting up to get a basic auth login for O365. Could you try going to <functionapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell and try running your script directly?

Comment: I'm getting a 403 error page trying to go to the address you sent

Comment: Weird, can you try accessing it by going to Function app settings > "Go to App Service Settings" > "Tools" > "Kudu" > "Go ->", and then clicking on "Debug Console" up top, choosing PowerShell, and trying from there.

Comment: Same result: Error 403 - This web app is stopped.

Comment: That's super weird. Could you try a new app? You might want to raise that issue on our MSDN forums. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/home?forum=AzureFunctions